# Oracle error ORA-01483: invalid length for DATE or NUMBER bind variable

Tags: sql, oracle

We are facing the below Oracle error while inserting a record in to the database.

```
ERROR SQL State: 72000 java.sql.SQLException: 
ORA-01483: invalid length for DATE or NUMBER bind variable
```

The table has two columns with the type as `varchar2(4000)`. When I am try to insert 4000 chars to either column1 or column2 only then it's inserting properly.

But when I try to insert 4000 chars to both the columns then the above error is coming.

Oracle version: 11g R1
JDK version: 1.4

Any thoughts / advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which driver version are you using?

Comment: the version of classes12.jar is 9.0.2.0.0 , when I replaced this Jar with the version of 10.2.0.4 then the insertion of 4000 chars for both columns at the same time is working properly. But I want to know do I need to take care of any points before I use this new version of the driver. Do you feel is it necessary to re-test the whole application where ever we are doing the DB Operation?

Comment: "Do you feel is it necessary to re-test the whole application where ever we are doing the DB Operation" - Testing is your piece of mind that your application works as required. If you change the method of access to the DB (even by upgrading from 9i to 10G) then you need to retest your application.

Comment: Are you sure that your 4000 chars are 4000 bytes? If at least one of them is 2 bytes, then...

Answer (score 0):

if length >1000 you can use Clob to save
this is a way to resolve ORA-01483 and ORA-01461

just like:

*`DefaultLobHandler lobHandler = new DefaultLobHandler();
LobCreator lobCreator = lobHandler.getLobCreator();
lobCreator.setClobAsString(ps, i + 1, (String) column.getValue());`*

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is about length of bind variable in SQL descriptor area

when declaring SQLDA, you should provide length for every value before use

so it looks like:

```
SQLDA   *binda;
binda = SQLSQLDAAlloc(SQL_SINGLE_RCTX, 2, NAME_SIZE, IND_NAME_SIZE); 
binda->N = 2; 

binda->V[0] = (char *) number; 
binda->L[0] = (long) sizeof (int); 
binda->T[0] = 3; 

binda->V[1] = (char *) date; 
binda->L[1] = (long) 7; /* oracle datatype 12 size */
binda->T[1] = 12;
```